# Which artifact file types are opened and which are downloaded?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

When Browsing artifacts from a Gitlab CI Job. I have observed that a recent change took away the possiblity to directly show `*.txt` and `*.log` files in the browser but instead download the files.

I found this issue which is related: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/211517 (it's old but I was able to open such files abou one month ago)

Now I wanted to know which files are opened and which are downloaded. Is there an official list?

I observed:

- Opened:

  - html
  - xml
- Downloaded

  - log
  - txt

Comment: Are you using gitlab.com or self-hosted gitlab instance? What browser are you using? In my own testing, I am able to view `.txt` artifacts in GitLab without downloading them.

Comment: It's a self-hosted instance using "GitLab Community Edition v16.5.1" I am using Google Chrome as browser. I have the same behaviour with Microsoft Edge browser.